# Tool hangs while performing soak test using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I was carrying out soak testing on my website with 200 requests in 1 ramp up second. I am using JMeter V2.11 . But the tool hung and the test stopped roughly after about 35 mins in 5 different attempts. Though there was nothing registered in the log files, I presume the listener "View Results Tree" is the culprit. 
Tool: Jmeter
Version 2.11
Duration: 1 hour
JRE used 1.7
RAM 4 GB.

If so what can I do? Is there any alternative ? Even disabling/enabling the listener during the test doesnt work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Any recommendations for a tool which does soak testing is also welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the listeners during the test execution will not be helpful.

since system RAM is only 4GB, my suggestion would be to run the test in Command line mode.

http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2009/03/31/using-apache-jmeter-in-non-gui-mode/

hope this will help